# Python socket programming sequence queries

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send queries coming from a client to a base server that forwards then to 2 more servers that the base server is connected to.

(Those 2 servers find a match with the query in their database, if it matches, they send the query back, if no match, they send nothing)

First I send the query from the base server to the 1st server called ts1, If I don't get a reply, I send it to 2nd server called ts2. If I don't get a reply from ts2 as well, I send a error host message to the client.

I've tried these while and inner while loops to accomplish this task but my program hangs after sending the first query. Because the ts1 server sends nothing on the first query.

How can I correct my code so it wont hang and the entire code executes? maybe its non-blocking or blocking of the sockets ? I don't know how that is implemented.

```
    while True:

        # receive a message from the client
        data_from_client = csockid.recv(1024)
        word = data_from_client.decode('utf-8').lower()

        if word == '':

            break

        print('[Client]: ' + word)
        print("[ls Server]: Sending " + word + " to ts1 & ts2 for Query....")

        ts1.send(word.encode('utf-8'))

        while True:

            search_from_ts1 = ts1.recv(1024)
            ts1_server_answer = search_from_ts1.decode('utf-8')

            print("[ls Server]: sending reply from ts1 server " + ts1_server_answer + " to Client")
            csockid.send(ts1_server_answer.encode('utf-8'))

            if not search_from_ts1:

                ts2.send(word.encode('utf-8'))

                while True:

                     search_from_ts2 = ts2.recv(1024)
                     ts2_server_answer = search_from_ts2.decode('utf-8')

                     print("[ls Server]: sending reply from ts2 server " + ts2_server_answer + " to Client")
                     csockid.send(ts2_server_answer.encode('utf-8'))

                     if not search_from_ts2:

                        print("[ls Server]: No match found in both ts1 & ts2")
                        error = " - Error:HOST NOT FOUND"
                        csockid.send(error.encode('utf-8'))

                        break
            break

        if not data_from_client:

            break
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger. if you don't get a reply form ts1 the recv method will block.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set a timeout, then try the other server, but that might make the code unacceptably slow. At this point you might want to explore [async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) functions which give you the instruments for doing this properly (sending the request to both servers "simultaneously" and then take whatever is available but have a timeout on both request replies).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the non-blocking sockets section in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html  for reference.  It tells you how to set up non-blocking sockets and the use of **select** to poll more than one socket.